# Gradle srcDirs path

Tags: java, gradle, antlr

[image]

Why is the path for sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs "generated-src/antlr/main" and not "generated-src/antlr"?

From the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html), it seems that the standard way of declaring a srcDir is to exclude the sourceSet name, for example:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: The snippet you're quoting is specifically meant to represent how to customise Gradle for a non-standard layout.

Comment: Do you know where I can find more info about this? It would never occur to me to either add "/main" after "generated-src/antlr" or to have antlr and main swap positions like that in the path.

Comment: In your build.gradle, you have two different spellings of the path (one with antlr/main, two with main/antlr) and three different ways to convert the string path to a File (new File, file(...) and plain string). Maybe you should start making them all consistent. Especially the file conversions work differently depending on the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

The [Gradle Java plugin convention](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout) is to place source sets file as follows: `src/<sourceSetName>/<type>`

That means `src/main/java` for the main Java files of a module, `src/test/groovy` for the Groovy test files, etc ...

As you can see from the example I gave, that convention is also respected by other plugins, Groovy, Scala, Kotlin, ...

Note that in the project above, locating the generated files inside the `build` directory would be better aligned with Gradle conventions as it would alleviate the need for modifying the `clean` task.

Comment: What I don't understand is the generated output folder path is "generated-src/main/antlr", which is also used to define the IDEA module srcDir. But for SOME reason, when defining the generated sourceSet, the java srcDirs is "generated-src/antlr/main". What is the pattern here and where is this documented?

Comment: There are two references to `generated-src/main/antlr` and one to `generated-src/antlr/main` in that build file. I believe the last one is an error. Hard to say for sure without more context.

Comment: Here's more context: https://github.com/C2H6O/language-playground ... Any other combination of paths just doesn't work